# Install extension in magento 2 - no app/code folder

Tags: magento2.2

I have downloaded a paid extension and the steps that they have provided to install are:
1. Unzip extension
2. Upload in app/code
3. Go to root in cmd prompt and run:
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
    php bin/magento cache:flush

The first issue is my magento version do not have app/code folder, I have checked this link:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90913/how-to-install-custom-extension-in-magento2

but that is also not working.
The extension which I have downloaded has following content in it when unzipped:

```
-- Block
-- etc
-- Gateway
-- Model
-- Observer
-- view
-- Changelog.md
-- composer.json
-- README.md
-- registeration.php
```

I have tried following steps:

```
1. create a folder in root
2. and then took all content of extension in that folder
3. Then I ran commands:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

but it didn't work.

Please let me know what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just create manually code folder in your app folder and put module there. The structrure must be like this: in your app/code folder (which you've created) you have Company/Module folders (from module you've copied).

Run **bin/magento setup:upgrade** after.